# What are the different aspects that need to be understood before leaving a job one month after starting?

Tags: united-states, resignation

I know there are a bunch of questions that have been asked on this same topic before but my question is slightly different.

A friend has an offer from a smaller company A and is also in the process of preparing for interview for a much bigger more competitive company B. He has spent more than in a year in preparation already and has an interview with company B in less than 5 weeks.

He hates his current job and does not want to lose out on the company A opportunity. If he gets an offer from B it will commence a month after starting with A.

He was planning to take a week of PTO to prepare for B after starting with A. I think he is aware that he may need to pay back the PTO amount if he leaves in a month.

He is wondering:

1. If there could be any other legal consequences if he leaves within a month of starting - assuming he is not signing any papers that talk about paying back hiring expenses etc.
2. Will company B find out about this 1 month position during or after interview in background check and will they care or ask?
3. What should he tell company A why he is leaving and if asked by company B why he left ( I guess this answer is very subjective, but what is the politically correct and polite answer to give)?

Comment: country and/or state

Comment: California, US -  The position is remote, based in Chicago

Comment: I'm honestly failing to see how this is any different from any of the multitude of other questions we have on this subject, even down to "your friend" who is apparently not able to post here themselves; the answers are the same every time.

Answer (score 3):

> If there could be any other legal consequences if he leaves in a month after starting - assuming he is not signing any papers that talk about paying back hiring expenses etc.

California is an at-will state so technically you can leave (and be fired) at any time for any reason or no reason at all. You friend should carefully read the contract and the policies of company A. They may very well have clauses in there that covers this case. A good example: hiring bonuses typically have a payback clause. Your friend might not have much of a choice there: often these are not negotiable so you have to sign them or let it go

> Will company B find out about this 1 month position during or after interview in background check and will they care or ask?

Quite possibly yes. Your friend was employed and so it should show up on their employment record and resume. Trying to actively hide this is a very BAD idea: short employment can be explained many different ways: lying is a hard "fire immediately and put on the never-speak-to-again list" in many places

> What should he tell company A why he is leaving and if asked by company B why he left ( I guess this answer is very subjective, but what is the politically correct and polite answer to give)?

If your friend is lucky, they will still be in a probationary period. A simple "I don't think this is a good fit for me" will do. This may burn bridges but there is no way to prevent this completely.

Answer (score 1):

1. No legal consequence unless explicitly stated in a written employment contract.
2. Background checks typically are looking for criminal records, and sometimes bad credit.  If a background check form is requesting former employer, OMIT the one-month employer.
3. He doesn't owe Company A an explanation.  If B doesn't know about A, don't mention it.  If B does know about A, "not a right fit" should suffice if there are any questions about A, but don't volunteer this info.

Loose lips sink ships.  Any information about employment with A should be shared on an absolutely-need-to-know basis.  I'd just carry on as if employment with A never happened.

Answer (score 0):

For these types of questions,
leaving personal opinion regarding taking the job with intent of leaving shortly, aside

**Only one answer, check your employment contract and employee handbook**